# How use AppEngine's Datastore Admin: Copy to Another App Feature

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently enabled AppEngine's Datastore Admin.  I do not understand the instructions on how to copy my data to another app.

> Note: The target application must
>   enable remote_api and must include
>   this application’s ID in its
>   HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID list.
>
> WARNING This application’s data is
>   writable. We can only guarantee a
>   consistent copy when the data being
>   copied is read-only. Note: Blobs
>   (binary data) will not be copied.

To enable the remote_api I included the following in the app.yaml:

```
 builtins:
    - remote_api: on
```

I have no idea what HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID is, and a Google search yields no results....any ideas?
[image]
[image]

Comment: any reference link about that feature?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk

Answer (score 7):

The datastore copy feature is currently available only for Python applications.

If you are using GAE for Java you must do the following steps:

Notes: Assuming you are copying from app `example1.appspot.com` to app `example2.appspot.com` and your Java `WEB-INF` app folder is located in `/Users/admin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

1. Download Python SDK
   https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python
2. Run the Python SDK
3. Create a new file inside your `WEB-INF` folder: `app.yaml`
4. Create a new file inside your `WEB-INF` folder: `appengine_config.py`
5. Deploy your new version (run in terminal): `appcfg.py -A example2 update **/Users/admin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`
6. Go to your `example1` datastore admin view and put: `datastore-admin.example2.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api`

app.yaml:

```
application: example2
version: datastore-admin
runtime: python
api_version: 1


builtins:
- remote_api: on
- datastore_admin: on
```

appengine_config.py:

```
remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = (
    'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID', ['example1'])
```

Comment: Do I need to use the python SDK or can I just upload the files (app.yaml and appengine_config.py) when I deploy my project from eclipse?

Comment: @Tiago Fernandes You save my day. Thanks. :) since `GAE` now use pythin2.7, `app.yaml` should be updated.

Comment: This is a better, more complete answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java and already tried [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#procedure_for_copying_a_datastore) and its not working(i had the same problem) i added:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servletclass>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in web.xml and update with this command: appcfg.py -A appid update /yourappfolder/war/WEB-INF

Strange but after i did that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GAE for Java you must do the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240060/1029088).

GAE now use Python 2.7. So you need to create your `app.yaml` as below.

```
application: example2
version: datastore-admin
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true


builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

The `datastore_admin` tool should enable through the admin console instead of enabling the builtin in your `app.yaml`.